# Replace all class usages using roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

**What I am trying to do:**
Let's assume we have a class `Class1` inside assembly `OldAssembly`.
This assembly is referenced by a number of unknown projects.
I am going to move this class into a new assembly `NewAssembly`, eventually name and namespace would also change. Now all usages must be adjusted.
I want to create a tool which will automate these code adjustments.

**What I did so far:**
I have played around with roslyn `Renamer`:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var originalSln = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(@"D:\spikes\ToBeFixed\ToBeFixed.sln").Result;

var project = originalSln.Projects.Single();
var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;

var renameFrom = compilation.GetSymbolsWithName(s => s.Contains("Class1")).Single();
const string renameTo = "Class2";
var optionSet = originalSln.Workspace.Options;
var modifiedSln = Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(originalSln, renameFrom, renameTo, optionSet).Result;

workspace.TryApplyChanges(modifiedSln);
```

but it renames also the source class. So I have looked into the `Renamer` code and tried to adapt it for my use case, but failed due to some internals used in there.

**Question:**
How can I automate code adjustments after moving a class from one assembly into another.

Comment: Would you be able to first rename everything, and then afterwards fix the original class name?

Comment: Yes, but I do not see a way reducing the scope of "rename back" to a single class. Changing just a class name in a class declaration is not enough.

Comment: So you need to change all usages *outside* the class? You want to keep the original class exactly the way it was?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you're looking for by:

1. Renaming all usages of the class throughout the entire solution
2. Replacing the renamed class itself with its original self.

   ```
   public async static Task TestingRenamer()
   {
       var code = @"
       using System;

       //We do not want to rename MyClass (we want to keep it the same)
       public class MyClass
       {
           public MyClass()
           {
           }
       }

       public class Program
       {
           public static void Main()
           {
               //We want to rename this usage
               var x = new MyClass();  
           }   
       }";

       var newClassName = "MY_NEW_CLASS_NAME";
       var document = getDocumentForCode(code);
       var compilation = await document.Project.GetCompilationAsync();

       var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
       var originalClass = root.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();

       var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(root.SyntaxTree);
       var originalSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(originalClass);

       //Rename all 
       var newSolution = await Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync(document.Project.Solution, originalSymbol, newClassName, document.Project.Solution.Workspace.Options);

       //Revert the original class
       var newDocument = newSolution.GetDocument(document.Id);
       var newSyntaxRoot = await newDocument.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
       var newClass = newSyntaxRoot.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Where(n => n.Identifier.ToString() == newClassName).Single();
       newSyntaxRoot = newSyntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(newClass, originalClass);
       newDocument = newDocument.WithSyntaxRoot(newSyntaxRoot);

       //We've now renamed all usages and reverted the class back to its original self.
       var finalSolution = newDocument.Project.Solution;
   }

   //Helper method to build Document
   private static Document getDocumentForCode(string code)
   {
       var ws = new AdhocWorkspace();
       var Mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
       var references = new List<MetadataReference>() { Mscorlib };
       var projInfo = ProjectInfo.Create(ProjectId.CreateNewId(), VersionStamp.Default, "MyProject", "MyAssembly", "C#", metadataReferences: references);
       var project = ws.AddProject(projInfo);

       var text = SourceText.From(code);
       var myDocument = ws.AddDocument(project.Id, "MyDocument.cs", text);
       return myDocument;
   }
   ```

Comment: getting error as "MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(Assembly)' is obsolete: 'Use CreateFromFile(assembly.Location) instead "

Comment: @KarthicG It sounds like they changed the API since I wrote this answer. If you get it working with CreateFromFile(), feel free to edit my answer with the correct API calls.